# PHP Socket - How to re-use a socket connection?

Tags: php, sockets, php-socket

i've the following situation:

**test.php** > When that page is loaded i perform one post via Ajax to a second page (socket.php)

**socket.php** > That page, receives the ajax request, and i create a socket (via php) to connect to a server (this is working). Then i send the information back to the **test.php**

Back to **test.php**, after a user specific interation, i need to send another post/ajax to **socket.php**, and i need to use the same socket connection that i used before. But i trying and failing.

In order to re-use the socket connection, is that a way to send a socket type resource via post/ajax? Or store that value somewhere?

Ps.: I really new on socket programming. So, sorry about evetually mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

In order to help future visitors...

After some research (and a lot of head ache), i stop to try re-use the socket connection using PHP.
Instead off i'm going to use WebSockets using JS. 'Cause it provides me a bi-directional communication, and a can re-use the connection as i want.